Find a subspace $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\mathcal{S}\not\subseteq\mathcal{H}$ and $(1,2,-1,3) \in \mathcal{S}^{\perp}$
Let $\mathcal{H} = \left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4 \ \middle| \ 3x_1 + 4x_2 - x_3 + x_4 = 0 \right\}$. $\\$
Find, if possible, a subspace $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that
$\\$
$\dim(\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{H}) = 1$, $\mathcal{S} \not\subseteq \mathcal{H}$, and $(1, 2, -1, 3) \in \mathcal{S}^\perp$.
Basis  for $\mathcal{H}$:
$3a+4b-c+d = 0$
$d = -3a-4b+c$
$(a,b,c,d) = (a,b,c,-3a-4b+c)$
$\mathcal{H}$ = $\{a(1,0,0,-3) + b(0,1,0,-4) + c(0,0,1,1)\mid a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\} $
$\mathcal{H}$ = $\langle (1,0,0,-3),(0,1,0,-4),(0,0,1,1) \rangle \implies \dim(H) = 3$
I also found $H^{\perp} = \langle 3,4,-1,1 \rangle$
From the dimension theorem, we know:
$\dim(\mathcal{S} + \mathcal{H})= \dim(\mathcal{S}) +  \dim(\mathcal{H}) - \dim(\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{H}) \\ \dim(\mathcal{S} + \mathcal{H}) = \dim(\mathcal{S}) +  3 - 1$
Also notice since $(1,2,-1,3) \in S^{\perp}$, its required that
$\mathcal{S} \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + 2x_2-x_3+3x_4=0\}$
My question is:
How do I find the intersection and see if any subset has dimension 1...?
$\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{H} \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1+2x_2-x_3+3x_4=0\}\cap \mathcal{H}$

What allowed you to write  $\dots- \dim(\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{H})=\dots - 1$?

Note that $\dim(\mathcal H\cap(1,2,-1,3)^\perp)=3+3-4=2$.
The conditions can therefore be reformulated:
$\mathcal S=L\oplus K$ where $L$ is an arbitrary line in $\mathcal H\cap(1,2,-1,3)^\perp$, and $K$ is an arbitrary line in $(1,2,-1,3)^\perp\setminus\mathcal H$.
